# Using python script to download google sheet as csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm using the python script on raspberry pi3 from this link- inserting my google email address and google sheet number into the script:

https://gist.github.com/Thuruv/dc0e2f781b8e095b9981f265647b8304

and then my google password as I run the script but I get the below errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Googlespreadsheets.py", line 53, in <module>
csv_file = gs.download(ss)
File "Googlespreadsheets.py", line 34, in download
"Authorization": "GoogleLogin auth=" + self.get_auth_token(),
File "Googlespreadsheets.py", line 29, in get_auth_token
return self._get_auth_token(self.email, self.password, source, 
service="wise")
File "Googlespreadsheets.py", line 25, in _get_auth_token
return re.findall(r"Auth=(.*)", urllib2.urlopen(req).read())[0]
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 435, in open
response = meth(req, response)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 548, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 473, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 556, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Answer (score 1):

Navigating to the URL in the code directly links [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps), displaying the warning from Google:

> **Important:** ClientLogin has been officially deprecated since April 20, 2012 and is now no longer available. Requests to ClientLogin will fail with a HTTP 404 response. We encourage you to migrate to OAuth 2.0 as soon as possible.

This code will fail with a 404 response, as your attempt demonstrates. Try moving this code to [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

Comment: Tried the script from this tutorial.  I was able to successfully do his other tutorial on listing files in google drive but not this one.

Comment: If you want to use someone’s tutorial using old Google ClientLogin, you’ll need to move the authentication portion of the script to OAuth instead. Here is the documentation for Python: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented an open source python command line utility https://pypi.org/project/google-sheets-to-csv/ that should works on pi3 as long you have python3 installed. If you want to integrate in a larger application you should be able to use it as third party API.

Basic usage on linux:

```
pip install google-sheets-to-csv
mkdir out
gs-to-csv <spreadsheet ID> <sheet selector (regex)> out/
```

I'll get one csv file per sheet that match the given regex selector.

If you've a browser installed on your pi3, first time you connect you'll be asked to allow read access to all your spreadsheets to the python application installed on your pi3. If you use your pi3 as a server without GUI you could use it on your computer and copy the generated token but I would recommand to use a google service account in that case and gives access to spreadsheets you want to download to that google account service.